# Hyperledger Fabric : grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "172.27.0.1:55920": remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am facing following error while trying to deploy hyperledger fabric 1.2 network on vm with tls enabled. Without tls enabled, it works fine.

**Logs from orderer**

> 2019-02-06 07:21:48.629 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 32c grpc:
>   Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from
>   "172.28.0.1:60654": remote error: tls: bad certificate  2019-02-06
>   07:21:49.631 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 32d grpc: Server.Serve failed
>   to complete security handshake from "172.28.0.1:60658": remote error:
>   tls: bad certificate  2019-02-06 07:21:51.242 UTC [grpc] Printf ->
>   DEBU 32e grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from
>   "172.28.0.1:60662": remote error: tls: bad certificate

**Logs from peer**

> 2019-02-06 07:05:39.616 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 048 Got
>   error: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050]
>   , at 7 attempt. Retrying in 1m4s  2019-02-06 07:06:46.619 UTC
>   [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 049 Failed connecting to
>   10.200.10.97:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded  2019-02-06 07:06:46.619 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 04a Failed obtaining
>   connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints:
>   [10.200.10.97:7050]  2019-02-06 07:06:46.619 UTC [deliveryClient] try
>   -> WARN 04b Got error: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050] , at 8 attempt. Retrying in 2m8s  2019-02-06
>   07:08:57.622 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 04c Failed
>   connecting to 10.200.10.97:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded 
>   2019-02-06 07:08:57.622 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 04d
>   Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the
>   endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050]  2019-02-06 07:08:57.622 UTC
>   [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 04e Got error: Could not connect to any
>   of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050] , at 9 attempt. Retrying in
>   4m16s  2019-02-06 07:13:16.625 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection ->
>   ERRO 04f Failed connecting to 10.200.10.97:7050 , error: context
>   deadline exceeded  2019-02-06 07:13:16.625 UTC [deliveryClient]
>   connect -> ERRO 050 Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to
>   any of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050]  2019-02-06 07:13:16.625 UTC
>   [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 051 Got error: Could not connect to any
>   of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050] , at 10 attempt. Retrying in
>   8m32s  2019-02-06 07:21:51.628 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection ->
>   ERRO 052 Failed connecting to 10.200.10.97:7050 , error: context
>   deadline exceeded  2019-02-06 07:21:51.628 UTC [deliveryClient]
>   connect -> ERRO 053 Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to
>   any of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050]  2019-02-06 07:21:51.628 UTC
>   [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 054 Got error: Could not connect to any
>   of the endpoints: [10.200.10.97:7050] , at 11 attempt. Retrying in
>   17m4s

I have looked at solutions provided on similar error but nothing seems to work.

Following is my docker compose file.

```
version: '2'

services:   ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.1
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/0cb4817b6da79bc68fad2fa8ce4f87589e30f42bf942e05000743da51177c9c1_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
--ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/7500db7dc4fa2cd8be9c4808e24d1e0aa9afc96e046e6b8f91c570823dfbd787_sk'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ADDRESSES=[127.0.0.1:7050]
      - ORDERER_HOST=orderer.example.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1
    extra_hosts: 
      - "orderer.example.com:10.200.10.97"
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/peer/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/peer/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/peer/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb.org1.example.com:5984
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/peer/tls
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb.org1.example.com

  couchdb.org1.example.com:
    container_name: couchdb.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
```